Attempting to deploy a BabylonJs website coded in typescript
I had learned to code babylonjs scenes in type script
import {Scene, Engine, FreeCamera, Vector3, HemisphericLight, MeshBuilder, StandardMaterial, Texture, CubeTexture, PBRMaterial, SceneLoader, AbstractMesh, ActionManager, SetValueAction, InterpolateValueAction, IncrementValueAction, Mesh, CannonJSPlugin, PhysicsImpostor, Size, Color3, int} from "@babylonjs/core"

import "@babylonjs/loaders"

import * as CANNON from "cannon"

export class FpController {

    scene: Scene
    engine: Engine
    box!: AbstractMesh
    sphere!:AbstractMesh
    cylinder!:AbstractMesh
    ground!:AbstractMesh
    sphereMat!: PBRMaterial
    x: int

    

    constructor( private canvas:HTMLCanvasElement){

        this.x = Math.floor( Math.random() * 2) +1;

        this.engine =new Engine(this.canvas, true)
        this.scene = this.CreateScene()

        
        if (this.x === 2){
            this.CreateEnvironment()
        }
        if (this.x === 1){
            this.CreateEnvironment2()
        }  
        
        
        
        

        

        // this.CreateImposter()

        this.CreateController()

        // this.Triggered()
        
        this.engine.runRenderLoop(()=>{
            this.scene.render()
        })

        
    }

and as of now I am trying to launch it as a website. I have tried github, "npm run build" and "Netlify", none of them have worked. Does anyone know what to do?
As of now I am trying to launch it as a website. I have tried github, "npm run build" and "Netlify", none of them have worked. Does anyone know what to do?

You're trying to do too much at once.

First figure out how to deploy a basic "Hello World" HTML web site.
Then figure out how to add JavaScript.
Then figure out how to add TypeScript.
Then and only then start figuring out how to incorporate BabylonJS.

